# knockout.js sorted and ratelimit not working together well, infinite loop

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js, observable

For some reason my sorted method here in conjunction with ratelimit is causing an endless loop.  I am not sure why it won't stop being hit.  If I remove the ratelimit or the sorted there is no endless loop, but if I use both it won't stop.

```js
function Unscheduled() {
    var self = this;
  self.games = ko.observableArray([]).extend({
            sorted: function(l, r) {
              return l.length > r.length ? -1 : 1;
            },
            rateLimit: { timeout: 0, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" }});

    self.changes = ko.observable(0);
    self.games.subscribe(function (changes) {
                console.log('Array Hit');
                self.changes(self.changes()+1);
        }, null, "arrayChange");
        
  self.games.push('test');
  
  self.addRemove = function() {
  self.games.remove('test1');
  self.games.push('test');
  }
}
    ko.extenders.sorted = function (obs, sortFunction) {
        ko.computed(function () {
        console.log('sorting');
            obs.sort(sortFunction)();
        });
    };

ko.applyBindings(new Unscheduled());
```

```html
<script src="https://exposureevents.com/scripts/knockout-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text: changes">

</div>
<button data-bind="click: addRemove">
Add/Remove
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the issue is related to `sort` method of `observableArray`. I guess when using that method it generates a change notification then it tries to sort again and goes in this forever loop. When using `sort` on "raw" array there is no such behavior:

```js
function Unscheduled() {
    var self = this;
  self.games = ko.observableArray([]).extend({
            sorted: function(l, r) {
              // return l.length > r.length ? -1 : 1;
              return l - r;
            },
            rateLimit: { timeout: 0, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" }});

    self.changes = ko.observable(0);
    self.games.subscribe(function (changes) {
                console.log('Array Hit');
                self.changes(self.changes()+1);
        }, null, "arrayChange");
        
  // self.games.push('test');
  self.games.push(0);
  
  self.addRemove = function() {
  // self.games.remove('test1');
  // self.games.push('test');
  self.games.push(Math.random() * 10000 | 0);
  }
  self.gamesText = ko.pureComputed(() => self.games.reversed().join('\n'));
}
    ko.extenders.sorted = function (obs, sortFunction) {
        ko.computed(function () {
            console.log('sorting');
            // obs.sort(sortFunction)();
            obs().sort(sortFunction);
        });
    };

ko.applyBindings(new Unscheduled());
```

```html
<script src="https://exposureevents.com/scripts/knockout-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text: changes">
</div>
<button data-bind="click: addRemove">
Add/Remove
</button>
<pre data-bind="text: gamesText"></pre>
```

Comment: I dont think this sorts after the first try, so the sorting isnt dynamic.

Comment: Indeed it is, you may just look at the results in the `pre` container, also you may see how it behaves without reactivity by changing `obs().sort(sortFunction)` into `obs.peek().sort(sortFunction)`. In fact there is no need to sort reactively in the context of extender, the extender should only know the dependencies and fire on external changes not it's own, so it is enough to just call the observable with `obs();` to set up that dependency.